# adding .live to click functions in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have an app that uses a lot of jquery stuff and we're adding up all our scripts in an init.js file which has a lot of `.live("click"), .live("hover")` etc, stuff plus some `if($(".classname").length)` etc.

I have a suspicion it MIGHT be slowing down our pages unnecessarily(some pages don't need some scripts). But what is a more elegant solution to this? We certainly won't like a separate file for each page that needs it, that's a pain to maintain. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: i dont think jscompress will do any better on this one as the reason its probably slowing down is processing all those live calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your page-specific things in functions and call the appropriate function on every page.

Another solution would be mapping URLs to functions and calling the functions applicable for the current URL automatically - then you would not need any JS on the pages itself.

For your live events you could use delegates on the body and give the body a page-specific class: `$('body.page-xyz').delegate('your-live-selector', 'click', function(){...})`

This only attaches an event handler if the body has the correct class.

Comment: +1 Pretty much what I was typing. :-) The second option is a bit too tightly-coupled for my taste, so I prefer an inline `script` block on each page that triggers the appropriate setup, but I was also going to include it as an option in case the OP feels differently about it.

Comment: mmm i'll look more into that delegate thing. so delegate just looks for the body's class first? does it also function the same as live in which it also attaches to dynamically created elements?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript) to load other js files from the main one.

Comment: You could, if you want to have further HTTP request overhead. Best practice is to *minimize* HTTP requests.