# should i convert all my live functions to delegates?

Tags: delegates, jquery

Based on my question here: [adding .live to click functions in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660401/adding-live-to-click-functions-in-jquery)

It seems that the general consensus is that delegate > live in performance purposes. Should I be converting all my lives to delegates? If so, why use the live function at all since delegate is performance wise better?

And does delegate "ignore" everything when it doesn't see my selector in the DOM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't refactor your code for performance if there aren't any visible problems. However, there are other issues with `live()` that may affect maintainability of your code:

- Live doesn't work with `stopPropagation()`.
- Live is like a global variable. Different instances of a class may interfere with each other if using `live()`.

As for why `live()` still exists - according to [this article](http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live):

> As a general best practice, never use
>   .live in your applications. After live
>   was introduced in jQuery, Justin
>   argued the need for better a event
>   delegation API, and delegate was
>   created. The main reason jQuery still
>   supports live is for legacy code.

Finally, `delegate()` works exactly like `live()`, except that it attaches the event handler to an element you specify, whereas `live()` attaches it to `document`. When events bubble up to the specified element, it ignores the event if it didn't originated from, or pass through, an element that matches the given selector.

Comment: so let's say i declare a delegate function on $("#mr-id"). Will the page performance(load, whatever) be the same if the div named #mr-id existed or not?

Comment: @corroded, with `delegate()` you must call it from a **parent** element. It won't work if you call it on a non-existent element. So you have to do: `$('#mr-id-parent').delegate('#mr-id', 'click', handler);`. In which case yes, performance is better.

Comment: yes i meant that. i mean, if #mr-id-parent didn't exist, will it still be the same as if it existed?  Basically I want to declare that delegate function in a universal application.js that is included in all views, whether it has #mr-id-parent or not. just wanted to make sure that was ok to use

Comment: @corroded, in that case no. Delegate **must** be used on an element that exists at the time it is called. If you can't find a parent that is guaranteed to exist, then you have to use `document`, in which case you should just use `live()`.

Comment: oh. so I had to make sure that document existed huh? what if i added a $("#mr-parent").length over the declaration?

Answer (score 0):

.live() would also ignore anything if it doesn't find the selector in the DOM. See how they are equivalent from the jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/delegate/:

Delegate is an alternative to using the .live() method, allowing for each binding of event delegation to specific DOM elements. For example the following delegate code:

```
$("table").delegate("td", "hover", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
});
```

Is equivalent to the following code written using .live():

```
$("table").each(function(){
    $("td", this).live("hover", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });
});
```